# Многопоточная программа с "тяжелыми вычислениями"

Tags: java, многопоточность, ряды

В условии задания: релизовать многопоточную программу, которая будет вычислять число Пи с помощью ряда Лейбница: 4*(1-1/3+1/5-1/7+1/9-...). Отдельный поток в бесконечном цикле считает ряд, главный поток может его приостановить, показать текущий результат вычислений. Во время вычислений при каждом просмотре Пи значение должно становиться точнее и точнее.

Каждый раз Пи равно 4. Значение не меняется. Не могу сообразить в чем дело, помогите пожалуйста разобраться, буду признателен.

Вот здесь Пи считается:

```
public class PI implements Runnable {
private float PI=0;
private long Time;
private boolean StopCalculation = false;
private Thread thread;
PI(String name){
    thread = new Thread(this,name);
    thread.start();
}
@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; ;i++) {
        synchronized (thread) {
            long TMP = System.currentTimeMillis();
            PI = PI + ((float)(Math.pow(-1, i) * (1 / (2 * i + 1))));
            Time += System.currentTimeMillis() - TMP;
            while (StopCalculation)
                try {
                thread.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
public long getTime() {
    return Time;
}
public float getPI() {
    return PI;
}
public void setStopProcess(boolean stopProcess) {
    StopCalculation = stopProcess;
}}
```

Здесь главная программа с меню:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Menu implements  Runnable 
{
private int menu;
private Thread thread;
private PI pi;

Menu(String name, PI pi) 
{
    thread = new Thread(this, name);
    this.pi = pi;
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        synchronized (pi)
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("1 Продолжить вычисления.");
            System.out.println("2 Приостановить вычисления.");
            System.out.println("3 Посмотреть текущий результат.");
            System.out.println("4 Узнать суммарное время, затраченное на вычисления.");
            System.out.println("5 Выход.");
            menu = in.nextInt();
            switch (menu) 
            {
                case 1: 
                {
                    System.out.println("Продолжаем вычисления");
                    pi.notify();
                    pi.setStopProcess(false);
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("Приостанавливаем вычисления");
                    pi.setStopProcess(true);
                    break;
                }
                case 3: 
                {
                    System.out.println("Полученное значение Пи: " + 4 * pi.getPI());
                    break;
                }
                case 4: 
                {
                    System.out.println("Время выполения" + pi.getTime());
                    break;
                }
                case 5: 
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                }
                default: 
                {
                    System.out.println("<Error>");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    PI pi = new PI("Leibnits");
    Menu menu = new Menu("Menu",pi);
}}
```

Comment: `1 / ` замените на `1.0 /`. А ещё лучше вообще уберите `* (1 `, ибо умножать на единицу бессмысленно.

Comment: А ещё подумайте: 1. Почему вы используете `float` вместо `double`; 2. Что будет когда `i` станет отрицательным; 3. Зачем вам бесполезные в данной ситуации два `synchronized`; 4. Почему у вас названия полей и переменных с заглавной буквы; 5. Почему `Scanner` каждый раз создаётся новый; 6. Действительно ли не стоит делать `StopCalculation` `volatile`; 7. Зачем вам в `Menu` создавать для него новый поток, если есть уже начальный (стартовый)

Answer (score 1):

Написал свой вариант кода с учетом рекомендаций [Regent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183458/regent) (вопрос - все ли сделал правильно?). Если использовать `double`, то вроде бы никаких проблем не встретил. Единственное, на что не знаю ответа -- "Что будет когда `i` станет отрицательным?".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PI implements Runnable{

    private double  dPI = 0;
    private long    lTime;
    private volatile boolean isStopCalculation = false;
    private Thread  thread;

    public PI() {
        thread = new Thread (this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long lTMP;

        for(int i = 0; ;i++) {      
            lTMP = System.currentTimeMillis();
            dPI += Math.pow(-1, i) / (2 * i + 1);
            lTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - lTMP;
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    while(isStopCalculation)
                        wait();
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }           
        } // for()      
    } // run()

    public double getPI() {
        return 4 * dPI;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return lTime;
    }

    public synchronized void pauseProcess() {
        isStopCalculation = true;
    }

    public synchronized void continueProcess() {
        isStopCalculation = false;
        notify();               
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int iMenu;
        PI pi = new PI();

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);          
        System.out.println("1 Продолжить вычисления.");
        System.out.println("2 Приостановить вычисления.");
        System.out.println("3 Посмотреть текущий результат.");        
        System.out.println("4 Выход.");

        while(true) {           
            iMenu = scan.nextInt();
            switch(iMenu) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.print("Продолжаем вычисления");
                    pi.continueProcess();                   
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {                   
                    System.out.print("Приостанавливаем вычисления");                    
                    pi.pauseProcess();                  
                    break;
                }
                case 3: 
                {
                    double p = pi.getPI();
                    System.out.println("Библиотечное значение Пи: " + Math.PI);
                    System.out.println("Полученное значение Пи  : " + p  + ",  время: " + pi.getTime());
                    System.out.println("Разница значений        : " + (Math.PI - p));
                    break;
                }
                case 4: 
                {
                    System.out.println("Конец!");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                }
                default: 
                {
                    System.out.println("<Error>");
                    break;
                }                   
            }  // switch()
        }  // while()       
    }  // main()
}
```

Comment: очень благодарен за помощь. Сам сделал  с учетом советов, но была проблема с тем, что поток падал, вычисления после остановки не возобновлялись.

Comment: А время нормальное получилось? А то у меня на одном компе время получалось отрицательным (!!). А на других -- нормально.

Comment: со временем все было нормально

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО, с помощью Stream API в Java 8 это можно сделать гораздо элегантней:

```java
        final int N = 1000; // контролирует точность вычисления
        final double pi = 4D * DoubleStream.iterate(1D, n -> n + 2D) // получаем все нечётные числа
                .limit(N) // ограничиваемся только первыми N нечётными
                .parallel() // распараллеливаем вычисления 
                .map(n -> ((n % 4D == 1D) ? 1D : -1D) * (1D / n)) // f(x) = -1? * 1/ x
                .sum();
        System.out.println("pi = " + pi);
```

Comment: Да, только вы никак промежуточный резулььат + приостановку обработки не можете сделать через стрим апи элегантно